# How to catch any string when it follows specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to catch any characters that follow `in` or`at` until the end of the line.

For example, given:

> Johen plays in the park.

The result should be:

`the park.`

I have tried:

```
text.match(/(?:in|at)\s+([\w\s].*)(\n)/g);
```

Comment: Remove `g` and `(\n)`. Grab `match[1]`.

Comment: `/(?:in|at)\s+([\w\s].*)(\n)/g.exec("Johen plays in the park\n")[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` modifier when used with `Strig#match()` omits the captures from the final result. Also, `\n` is not necessary as `.` matches any char but  a line break char.

Note that `\s+` already consumes all whitespaces after `in` or `at`, thus, the `\s` is redundant in `[\w\s]`, you may keep just `\w`, or `\S` there.

Besides, it makes sense to match `in` or `at` as whole words if you only want to match after these two prepositions and not after `sin`, `sat`, etc.

```js
 var text = "in the park";
 var m = text.match(/\b(?:in|at)\s+(\w.*)/);
 if (m) {
   console.log(m[1]);
}
```